# Why do use "program" to refer to "input"?

Tags: word-usage

> I step away from her, and see her phone sitting on her desk, so I pick
>   it up and **program** my number in with her contacts and then hand it to
>   her so she sees.

Is it common to say "program some text into some app"? I just know it today, there is such an expression. I only knew "input" before.

Comment: input and program are technical terms. Your sentence is just everyday speech by cellphone users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can both be used to describe the same action, but they can also mean different things.

I need to first describe a different word before I get to *input*.

> I am *typing* my number into her contact list.

This simply means that you entering the numbers on the keypad of your phone. You could also use the same verb when talking about calling someone:

> I am *typing* her number into my phone's dialer.

When you *type* something in, there is no inherent concept of it being temporary or permanent. Whether the thing you type is remembered or not is based on context.

---

> I am *programming* my number into her contact list.

The verb *program* is used in the sense of typing something in, but *also* with the implication that it will remain permanent.

When you *program* a number into something, you will not need to program it in *again* at some later date—unless something unexpected happens that makes the application forget the information.

In software terms, what you are doing could be considered the equivalent of *teaching* an application how to do something. You are defining the values of one or more variables to which it will refer back at a future date.

By extension, you would normally ***not*** say something like this and mean it to be taken *literally*:

> I am *programming* her number into my phone's dialer.

This might sound a bit strange, because a dialer doesn't normally *remember* anything in the same sense that a contact list does. It might be assumed that if you said this you actually *meant* that you were programming the number into the contact list *used* by the dialer, but that's something different. Dialing applications often do remember the last number dialed—but unless you were somehow entering the number in such a way that it would never be forgotten, no matter how many different calls were made afterwards, it would be unusual to use *programming* rather than *typing*.

---

So, *typing* implies a simple action, while *programming* implies the same action but *also* results in a permanent result (the action is remembered so that it either doesn't need to be repeated later on, or so that the software behind the application knows to make use of it in some permanent way).

---

The use of *input* is ambiguous. It can be taken in the simple sense of *typing*, or it can be taken in the more permanent sense of *programming*. Which sense of the word is meant or understood is commonly conveyed through context.

> I am *inputting* her number at the dialer prompt.

This implies that it's temporary and won't be remembered. It's the same thing as saying *typing*.

> I am *inputting* her number into my contact list.

This implies that it's a number that will remembered for future use. It's the same things as saying *programming*.

---

After discussing all of that, the specific phrase *I am programming some **text** into some app* is a little unusual.

You may be *typing* some text into some app, but you wouldn't really say you are *programming* some text into it. Text represents something else. In the context of a contact list, when we say *number*, we actually mean *phone number*. But if we say *text*, it's not at all clear what piece of information that would represent.

(Even in the case of a text message, that's something we would *type* or *send*, not something that we would *program* to be remembered for later recovery, repetition, or retrieval.)

So, instead of this:

> I am programming ***some text*** into my app.

I would say this:

> I am programming ***[a name / an address / a number / a note / some piece of information]*** into my app.

The piece of information is *represented by* the text you are typing, but you are programming the information itself.

Comment: I really don't think program is right here at all. The OP is rather confused about usage. input and program are just not right here.

Answer (score 0):

I have certainly heard people talk this way, especially older people less comfortable with technology.  But I googled "program his/her number" and got a lot of hits from apparently younger people.  I would say "add my number to her contacts" instead.

I don't hear people talking about "programming" some text into some random app.  But "program" is commonly used to mean "configure".  Even technical people say "program the remote" to mean "configure the remote" or "set up the remote", even though there's no actual programming involved.

Comment: Do you mean only number can be "progammed", text can't be?

Comment: I think "program" is used for entering codes or numbers, not text.  At least I can't think of a case where "program" is used for ordinary text.

Answer (score 0):

**The simplest way to say this in everyday language** is:

EDITED:
"I move away from her, and see her phone sitting on her desk, so I pick it up and **put** my number in her contacts (list) and then hand her the phone so she sees it there.

We say **put or add a number to (a list of) contacts"". **This is not technical lingo at all.**

"put my number **in with** her contacts" is wrong.

And program is wrong here too.

- add a number to a list of contacts
- put a number into a list of contacts

or contacts' list

In fact, most smartphones say: **Add** number to contacts, remove number from contacts, block number, etc. Or how to add a contact to your contacts list.

This is just one example. **The point is the word add is used with number or contact.**

[Android Phone](https://www.dummies.com/consumer-electronics/smartphones/droid/how-to-add-a-contact-to-your-droid-x-contacts-list/)